# i want to get the year from date column of my entity in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpql

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "schedule_assignees",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
        private List<Person> assignedTo;
```

service method :

```
 @Override
        public List<Integer> getScheduleYearsBy(Employee employee, Company company) {
            Person person = personRepository.findByIdAndCompany(employee.getId(),company);
            return scheduleRepository.findYearsBy(Arrays.asList(person), company);
        }
```

Repository method

```
 @Query(value = "select distinct EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.date) from Schedule s where (s.assignedTo in ?1)  " +
        "and (s.company = ?2) and s.archived=false")
List<Integer> findYearsBy(List<Person> person, Company company);
```

this repository method workg fine in eclipse link. but in hibernate its getting the exception as follows

```
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [com.orsbv.hcs.model.Employee@6a5] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [com.orsbv.hcs.model.Employee@6a5] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:368)
```

can someone suggest the way to get it working in hibernate?

Comment: Try using the HQL `year` function.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen  not working

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with accessing the year. Read it. It says: *Parameter value [com.orsbv.hcs.model.Employee@6a5] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection*. Your query uses `s.assignedTo in ?1`, so the first parameter should be a collection, but it's an employee.

Comment: JB Nizet ---question updated with proper info. still not working

Comment: Apparently, you didn't read my comment. Read it again. The problem is that you're passing an employee for an argument that should be a collection. You haven't changed that, so the problem won't disappear.

Comment: Apparently, you didn't read my comment. Read it. The problem is that you're passing an employee for an argument that should be a collection. You haven't changed that, so the problem won't disappear.

Comment: JB Nizet--person is the super type of Employee and now i am sending Arrays.asLIst(Person) as parameter. DId you catch you ?

Comment: Then the exception can't possibly be the one you posted, since it still complains that the first argument is an enmployee and should be a collection.

Comment: JB Nizet--still it returns the same exception as i posted.i m also surprised.

Comment: actually the problem is regarding the hibernate lazy loading issue. after debug i found it could not fetch lazy associations properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally changing the repository method and using QueryDSL and predicate solve this

```
 @Override
    public List<Integer> findYearsBy(Person employee, Company company) {

        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        predicate.and(QSchedule.schedule.company.eq(company));
        predicate.and(QSchedule.schedule.archived.eq(Boolean.FALSE));
        predicate.and(QSchedule.schedule.assignedTo.any().eq(employee));

        return getQuerydsl()
                .createQuery()
                .from(QSchedule.schedule)
                .where(predicate)
                .select(QSchedule.schedule.date.year())
                .distinct()
                .fetch();
    }
```